# How Can I reduce the fontsize of footnotes in LaTeX beamer?

Tags: beamer, footnotes, fontsize

I use footnotes for image-references in my LaTeX beamer presentation. Is it possible to reduce the `footnotesize` for thoses references?

Is it also possible to have two different footnotesizes on the same slide - one for image-references and one for references to the literature?

Comment: Can you show us an example of your usage?

Comment: It sounds as if you might want to rethink the content of your slides. That is, how helpful will these be for your audience? (I realise that the image ones are probably legally required... sigh... even if they will mean nothing to anybody. But maybe that's a good reason to rethink the others...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a suggestion to reduce the size of all footnotes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \tiny%
  \parindent 1em\noindent%
  \raggedright
  \hbox to 1.8em{\hfil\insertfootnotemark}\insertfootnotetext\par%
}%
\setlength\footnotesep{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame-Titel}
    Figure\footnote{Footnote A}

    Text\footnote{Footnote B}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

It is also possible to have different sizes of the footnotes.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newcommand\figurefootnote[1]{%
  \setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
    \parindent 1em\noindent%
    \raggedright
    \hbox to 1.8em{\hfil\tiny\insertfootnotemark}\tiny\insertfootnotetext\par%
  }%
  \footnote{#1}%
  \setbeamertemplate{footnote}[default]
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Frame-Titel}
    Figure\figurefootnote{Footnote A}

    Text\footnote{Footnote B}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wanted to use the package `footmisc`. Unfortunately your (first) solution does not work then. Do you know why?

Comment: Works the package `footmisc` together with the `beamer` class at all?